# Javacard: error on static array initialization in package build with ant-javacard

Tags: java, ant, javacard

I have the following toy code for a library package with a static array:

```
package testapplets.library;
import javacard.security.RandomData;

public class SomeLibrary {
    public static final short TRUE = (short) 0x5AA5;
    public static final short FALSE = (short) 0xA55A;

    public static final byte[] test = { 'a', 'b', 'c'};

    public static short booleantest(boolean b) {
            return b ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    public static RandomData getRandom() {
        return RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);
    }
}
```

and the following ant task to build the library package:

```
  <target name="libtest" depends="prepare">
    <javacard jckit="${converter.sdk}">
      <cap targetsdk="${target.sdk}" sources="src/library" package="testapplets.library" aid="11:22:33:44:55" export="lib" output="build/libtest.cap" version="1.0"/>
    </javacard>
  </target>
```

but I am getting the following error message:

```
  [convert] [ INFO: ] Converter [v3.1.0]
  [convert] [ INFO: ]     Copyright (c) 1998, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
  [convert]     
  [convert]     
  [convert] [ INFO: ] conversion completed with 1 errors and 0 warnings.
  [convert] error:  Static array initialization in class testapplets/library/SomeLibrary in library package not allowed.
```

Why is static array in a library problematic? builds fine if I remove the static array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly using `new` in field initialization is forbidden in Java Card. You either have to perform the `new` from within the static `install` method (or a method called from `install`) or you can mark the field `private`, in which case the array is stored in the constant pool. I would strongly recommend the latter. Basically, no `static` code execution is allowed.

Using `TRUE` and `FALSE` as public static fields is not a good idea either, as they would be reference lookups, which is vulnerable to timing oracles. The whole idea of having `TRUE` and `FALSE` defined this way is to protect against such oracles as well as fault injection; I suggest to make them `private`.